# How to export table from heroku production database locally to excel from console using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, excel, export-to-excel

I know how to export table in Rails to formated Excel file: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

But how to do that from console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of option here.

Firstly, you could wrap up some ruby code into a rake task that creates the Excel spreadsheet and then spits it onto S3 for you to pick up later.  This would be run via the CLI:

```
heroku run rake export_data
```

OR

You could spin up a Postgres console `heroku pg:psql` and export your data to a CSV locally directly with a query such as those discussed here:  http://ru05team.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/export-postgresql-into-csv.html

Note: `pg:psql` gives you a full interactive PSQL session with your production database as if it were local.  Be careful when messing direct with a production database.

Answer (score 41):

Connect to your Heroku database by using

```
heroku pg:psql
```

Then run the sql command to get the csv file e.g.

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM users) TO dump.csv CSV DELIMITER ','
```

Use \q to exit.

After executing the commands dump.csv would have been created in your local environment

Comment: If you want the headers just add HEADER at the end: `COPY (SELECT * FROM users) TO '/tmp/file.csv' CSV HEADER;`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use (it's based off @algometrix's answer), it will escape quotes contained in strings:

1. Open postgres console in heroku with `heroku pg:psql`
2. This will ensure any quotes contained in strings are escaped accordingly

```
\copy (SELECT * FROM users) TO dump.csv WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER TRUE, FORCE_QUOTE *)
```